# Robolectric and Mockinto

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I'm new to Robolectric and Mockito.
I try to write a simple unit test, but the static final values from
my Peferences class are null, and I can't find out how to solve it.

Comment: Share your code. Also be aware that **Mockito** can not mock static and finals

Comment: Hi,
I'd like to test **download banner** method at this class http://pastebin.com/EYCycQbHI. This is my **test** http://pastebin.com/XYDpSBAW, and from this class I can't get the static final url http://pastebin.com/bEcgRPjX.
When I used MockitoTestRunner JsonObject.toString() returned null, so I switched to RoboletricTestRunner, anyway I'm very confused about unit tesing in android.
I use gradle in my project, but now I'm very confused about I've to use Mockito or Roboletctric for unit testing, or use both of them together.

Comment: Hi, I was wrong, the IndexPreferences.ADVERTICUM_ADVERT isn't null. I pass this variable as an argument to OkHttpRequest, and when I write out the request I get this:
Request{method=POST, url=null, tag=null}
but when I write out the variable I get this output:
url: http://forrest.adverticum.net/ia/
So I think, the reqeust's toString() is mocked and return null for the url.

Comment: Ok, my test is almost successfull. I have to init my ADVERTICUM_ID variable like this
http://pastebin.com/s4D4WMim

    @InjectMocks
    Adverticum adverticum;
but I can inject adverticum into my class, but Adverticum's dependencies aren't injected (SharedPreference)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can stub class level variables like below.

Example:

```
    Class Abc{
    private static final variableName = null;
     -----;
      ----;
    rest of the code;
    }
```

--Steps to Mock private static fields using Powermockito.

1) Field field = PowerMockito.field(Abc.class,"variableName");

2) field.set(Abc.class, variableValue);

PS- Make sure that you have used @PrepareforTest(Abc.class);

Hope it's useful.

Comment: Thanks,
at this time my static final variables are ok, but I have this issue
I have this class: http://pastebin.com/7Zx2zJYM
and I can't find out how to instatiate it in a unit test, shared preferences is allways null.